# Kotlin Android - Is there a way to define the Views only one time in a class?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my code I make use of the following Views in XML:

```
        val googleButton: Button = findViewById<View>(R.id.google_login) as Button
        val loginWithEmailText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.login_with_email_text)
        val emailLoginButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.email_login_button)
        val createAccountButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.email_create_account_button)
```

This code is extracted from a function inside my Kotlin class. Whenever I have to access these views, I need to write this code all over again.

Is there any way that I can access them from only one place in my class code? I tried putting them outside but the app won't start.

Thank you

Comment: If your concern is all the `findViewById()` calls, use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). If your concern is having to do this in multiple places, define your properties as `lateinit var` values in your class and assign values to them after your layout is set up (e.g., after `setContentView()` in an activity).

Comment: Add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in starting of your `build.gradle` (app level) file and use the views directly by their `IDs` like `email_create_account_button.setOnClickListener{}` or `login_with_email_text.text`. You can use this way in any function of your class without even the need of initializing them using `FindViewById()`. In Fragment, use the just use the view or root as `view.login_with_email_text` or `view.email_create_account_button` in onCreateView and in other function, use requestView() as `requestView().textView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define these fields as a part of your class and initialize them once you set the layout resource for your `Activity`/`Fragment`. If you put these lines 1:1 in the class body, the initialization will fail, since the layout has not been inflated yet.

Please get familiar with the concept of lifecycle, so that you can understand how to approach View related topics: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Please check out this snippet for a sample code:

```kotlin
class MyActivity: Activity() {
    lateinit var textView: TextView
    lateinit var button: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my)

        // initialize your views here
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_id)
        button = findViewById(R.id.button_id)
    }

    fun someOtherFunction(){
        // you can reference your views here like normal properties
        button.setOnClickListener { v -> callAnotherFunction() }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Since you are on Android, you might be interested in using Kotlin synthetic properties for referencing views without the whole boilerplate of finding them: https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/. It's no longer a  recommended practice to make use of it, but it's handy in some cases anyway.

Comment: I was able to make it a little better by putting them in my onCreate method, after the setContentView. And then passing them as props to the functions where I need them. But what I want is to access them anywhere, even outside of onCreate. Any example code you can provide?

Comment: I have just updated the answer with a code snippet. Please check it out if it helps.